# High Memory Usage with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, oracle.manageddataaccess

I need a little help here.

I'm facing a problem now with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.

I have a class written for centralize oracle queries (`Clases.Oracle()`), which works perfectly, but with one query the memory usage rises up to 1GB, which is not a real problem, considering that the resultset has about 260.000 rows in the worst scenario. The real problem is that it never frees that memory, and if I execute that query again, rises up to 2GB, been that the higher limit so far.
[image: Diagnostic Tools]

I've tried adding `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` with no results.

My command execution function in `Clases.Oracle()` is:

```
        private DataTable ExecuteReader(string package, ref OracleParameter[] parametros, string owner)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            using (var cn = new OracleConnection(_connection_string))
            {
                using var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = $"{owner}.{package}";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (var par in parametros)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
                    }
                    using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    dt.Load(rdr);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   
                    throw new Exceptions.OracleException(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn?.Close();
                    cmd?.Dispose();
                    cn?.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

I'm using the `using` clause, so the objects are disposing.

And I'm calling the connection with this function:

```
        public List<AuditoriaUsuarios> ObtieneAuditoriaUsuarios(long incluyeCargoRol = 0)
        {
            var ora = new Clases.Oracle();
            var param = new OracleParameter[]
            {
                ora.AddInParameter("PIN_INCLUYECARGOROL",OracleDbType.Decimal, incluyeCargoRol),
                ora.AddOutCursor("CUR_OUT"),
                ora.AddOutParameter("PON_CODE", OracleDbType.Decimal),
                ora.AddOutParameter("POV_ERROR", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
            };
            var result = ora.ExecuteReader<AuditoriaUsuarios>($"{_PCK}.p_AUDIT_USUARIOS", ref param);
            if (ora.HayError(param))
            {
                throw new Exceptions.OracleException(ora.CodigoError, ora.MensajeError);
            }
            //GC.Collect();
            //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            return result;
        }
```

`Clases.Oracle()` doesn't need to be Disposable, because all the objects that I'm using are Disposable, and are being disposed, and 2 strings for the ConnectionString and the name of the Database Owner.

This is a Memory Usage dump from VS
[image: Memory Usage]

You can see an oracle related object (`OracleInternal.Common.ZoneValue`) using a lot of memory way long after the ExecuteReader finished and the results where returned.

Don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Edit:
I've forgot. This is a ASP .Net Core x64 WebAPI, using .NET Core 3.1 and C#, with Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Edit2:
I know it's dirty, but adding this to `ObtieneAuditoriaUsuarios` made things a little better. (In this case I don't care about CPU usage, because this data extraction it's supposed to be executed a few times a week, and is not part of everyday operation):

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

Edit3:
I've sent 8 simultaneous requests and the memory usage rised up to 3GB in some tests. But only it takes 1 request with a filter that returns less than 100rows, and the memory usage drops to less than 1GB

[image: Memory Usage Drop]

Comment: Does the memory change if you call GC.Collect()?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no, had no effect calling GC.Collect().

Comment: Are you freeing up the Reader in `ObtieneAuditoriaUsuarios` ?

Comment: @Loudenvier do you mean de data reader disposed on ExecuteReader function??
using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

Comment: @AngeloBernardi Were you able to resolve your issues with the high memory consumption?

Comment: hi @silkfire. Nope, I wasn't able to do so. And as it was a problem only in this particular method of one API, we stopped the search of solutions, because it's working like a charm in over 30+ other APIs.

Comment: Okay, so you had other methods calling the Oracle database in your code but only this particular one caused you issues? Interesting...

Comment: All the methods have the same behaviour, because them all use the same implementation, but in this particular one, due the large amount of rows returned (260k or more), the memory usage was noticeable. And the real problem is that no memory was freed after the execution ended and all the objects were disposed.